# how to delete row in UItableView using websync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I trying to delete a row when get real time data. Below is my code

**Function Class**

```
 public static void SubscribeUpdateMatchOddsParlay(UITableView tableview , List<DSMatch> lstDetails, ParlayTableSource abc)
        {
            string strUpdate = "Update"
            Client.Subscribe<string>(new SAMatchClient.SubscribeArgs<string>()
            {
                OnReceive = (g) =>
                {
                    Update appdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update>(g); 

                        abc.refresh(tableview);
                } 
            }, strUpdate);
        }
```

**TableSource Class**

```
public void refresh(UITableView tableView)
        {
            try {
                InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0);
                    tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                    tableView.ReloadData();

                }); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            } 
        }
```

**Error shown:**

Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

How can I delete a row in UItableView?

Comment: You do not want to `DeleteRows` and then `ReloadData`, if you are removing the *visual* row, call DeleteRows and manually remove it from your table's data source if needed. `ReloadData` should only be called when you want to completely reload the entire table (footers, headers, etc... )

Comment: thx for reply, still the same error. May I know what is the different between DeleteRows and DeleteSections?

Comment: what you want to do

Comment: DeleteRows only delete only rows while DeleteSections remove entire rows and section .

Comment: hi @KKRocks, when I get real time data and will update data into UItableView. Just simple flow, but I try few days and  I'm new in xamarin.

Comment: Finally find out the problem, I forgot to remove data source data, so in NumberOfSections method different amount. Thx all support